# Posting to SQL with JQuery, Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, post

I have run into a small problem which I can't seem to figure out.

I am creating an application that when a user clicks a button, depending on which button they click, it will post a number into the database.

There are 9 numbers (0-9) and if they click 0 then 0 gets put into the database, if they click 1 then 1 gets put into the database, etc...

I have an onclick call using JQuery and Ajax to submit the data silently:

```
$(function(){
    $('#1A').click(function(e) {  
        alert("You clicked 1A");
        var poll_ans = 1;
      $.ajax
      ({ 
          url: 'postpoll.php',
          data: {"pollAns": poll_ans},
          type: 'post',
          success: alert("Submitted " + poll_ans)
      });

    });
 });
```

This works fine, and when I click the DIV with ID 1A I get the alert, and the "Submitted!" alert.

However, it does not post to the SQL Database. When I test the postpoll.php file by itself setting the variables in the URL it seems to load indefinitely.

Here is my code:

postpoll.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$mysqli=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isSet($_POST['pollAns']))
{
$answer=intval($_POST['pollAns']);
$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES '$answer'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}
?>
```

Not sure what the problem is here - I am sure I missed something, and it's probably a simple solution!

Also, a side note - I eventually want to make it where the can only vote once, would the best way to accomplish this to simply set a cookie, then check if that cookie is present before posting? I know they could circumvent this by clearing their cookies, but it's not a problem.

SOLUTION:
It would appear that the culprit was CloudFlare. After checking on the httpd.conf file it showed that the sql connection was timing out. This was due to the fact that I was trying to connect to the DB using the actual URL, which is routed through CloudFlare's servers. In order to get to the actual physical server, I ended up using the IP. You can also add a DNS record that points to the IP and make sure you have it not being routed through CloudFlare.

Suggested Action in the Future: Remember that you are using CloudFlare!

Comment: Try "isset" instead of "isSet", also set a session in the if statement. `if (isset($_POST['pollAns'])) { $_SESSION['verify'] = "true"; }` then echo $_SESSION['verify'] to see if the page is even getting to the sql statement

Comment: Have you tried changing you `post` declaration without quotes, EG `{pollAns: poll_ans}`

Comment: Also: $result = mysqli_query($query); <- see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the culprit was CloudFlare. After checking on the httpd.conf file it showed that the sql connection was timing out. This was due to the fact that I was trying to connect to the DB using the actual URL, which is routed through CloudFlare's servers. In order to get to the actual physical server, I ended up using the IP. You can also add a DNS record that points to the IP and make sure you have it not being routed through CloudFlare.

Suggested Action in the Future: Remember that you are using CloudFlare!

Answer (score 0):

When you establish the connection you name it `$con`, then you try to query using the variable `$mysqli`. Change `$con` to `$mysqli` when establishing the connection. I also changed `VALUE` to `VALUES` and added single brackets around `$answer`.

```
<?php
session_start();
$mysqli=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***"); // Change from $con to $mysqli
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isSet($_POST['pollAns']))
{
$answer=intval($_POST['pollAns']);
$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES '$answer'"; // Add single brackets around $value and changed VALUE to VALUES
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__); // Here you are using $mysqli to perform query
}
?>
```

Comment: Ahh, that is certainly a major typo on my part - However, it's still not posting to the DB for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure your login credentials are correct? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I think it is timing out on connection, the httpd error log result:
  [Thu Jul 24 19:21:15.163404 2014] [:error] [pid 3038] [client ***] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in postpoll.php on line 3
    [Thu Jul 24 19:21:15.163519 2014] [:error] [pid 3038] [client ***] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in postpoll.php on line 15

Comment: I fixed it, It was cloudflare. I had to give it the actual IP instead of trying to route it through CloudFlare. Sometimes I forget it is enabled!

Comment: @Christopher I'm glad you fixed it! My next guess would've been to change the `mysqli_connect` to a `$mysqli = new mysqli()`. You should post your solution and accept it as an answer when you can. And don't be shy giving out +1's for helping answers :)

Comment: I will write up what I did. I don't see an option to +1?

Comment: @Christopher you click the arrow pointing upwards above the `0` on each post you found useful.

Comment: Says I am not allowed because I require 15 reputation points :\

Comment: Thanks for all the help though @Simple - you caught my typos :) That's a +1 in my book!

Comment: @Christopher glad to hear :) Good thing you finally got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your login credentials are correct. Also you have not properly handled the success and error events in your ajax request and alert the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try "isset" instead of "isSet", also set a session in the if statement. if (isset($_POST['pollAns'])) { $_SESSION['verify'] = "true"; } then echo $_SESSION['verify'] to see if the page is even getting to the sql statement.

See if changing the $mysqli->query($query) to this changes anything: `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);` (this shouldn't, I know that both ways work)

> Also, a side note - I eventually want to make it where the can only vote once, would the best way to accomplish this to simply set a cookie, then check if that cookie is present before posting? I know they could circumvent this by clearing their cookies, but it's not a problem.

You can check the table first to see if that users IPAddress is listed:

```
$sq = "select * from test where IPAddr = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'";
$qu = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sq);
// if it does then the mysqli_num_rows will return 1 or greater.
if (mysqli_num_rows($qu) == 0) {
    $query = "Insert into"...
}
```

Comment: Only problem with IP address is that it is going to be at an even where most people will be connected to wifi on their phones. So everyones IP would be the same.

By the way, I fixed the initial problem, it was due to CloudFlare - I often forget it is enabled.

Comment: Ah okay, do you make them log in? Then you could check for their log-in session in place of the Remote Addr

Comment: There is no login - I am thinking about having the Speaker have a PHP page that they can start a unique session, then when the Clients go to the page, they will grab the current session, and then make posts to the database. Also, if they click another button, it will remove their last answer, and update it by inserting their new answer in the DB. This way, everytime the Speaker starts a new session, it will be a different database. I could have each table have a column for sessionID, ClientID and a column for their answer. Still trying to work it out in my head. What do you think?

Comment: That would work well, you would be including the speaker ID in the sql statement and that would allow a user to vote once per session they are included in. Though you still have the problem of voting only once. I don't like recommending using cookies, although it is an option. You have some people who disable them in browsers, clear them, fake them, etc. You could give the user a unique session ID, though that will not prevent them from completely closing out and re-entering.